# React-Native Google Auto Complete - Unhandled promise

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/GooglePlacesAutocompleteExample/Example.js to help users find their address for shipping.

I am using the browser api key from google places. I am using an iOS device and simulator. However I just see unhandled promise anytime I type. (see pic below) I have also enabled App transport security to allow arbitrary loads. I get no suggestions at all. I have tested my keys in the browser with a url and it works so I know my account is activated and working. I also do not see any errors in the cloud console.

```
         <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                            placeholder='Search'
                            minLength={2}
                            autoFocus={false}
                            returnKeyType={'search'}
                            keyboardAppearance={'light'}
                            listViewDisplayed={false}
                            fetchDetails={true}
                            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
                            renderDescription={row => row.description}
                            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                                console.log(data, details);
                                this.setState({ location: data.structured_formatting.main_text, user_long: details.geometry.location.lng, user_lat: details.geometry.location.lat })
                            }}
                            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
                            getDefaultValue={() => ''}
                            textInputProps={{
                                ref: (input) => { this.fourthTextInput = input }
                            }}
                            query={{
                                // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                                key: 'MY_API_KEY',
                                language: 'en',
                                region: "US", //It removes the country name from the suggestion list
                                // types: '', // default: 'geocode'
                                components: 'country:us'
                            }}
                            styles={{
                                container: { width: 300 },
                                textInputContainer: {
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                    margin: 0,
                                    width: 200,
                                    padding: 0,
                                    borderTopWidth: 0,
                                    borderBottomWidth: 0
                                },
                                textInput: {
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    minWidth: 40,
                                    borderColor: "#cbb4c0",
                                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                    color: '#5d5d5d',
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                },
                                description: {
                                    color: '#ac879a',
                                    fontWeight: '300'
                                },
                                predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                                    color: '#1faadb'
                                }
                            }}
                            currentLocation={false}
                            nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
                            GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{// available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
                            }}
                            GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                                // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
                                rankby: 'distance',
                                type: 'cafe'
                            }}
                            GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
                                // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
                                fields: 'formatted_address',
                            }}
                            filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']}
                            debounce={200}
                        />
```

[image]

Comment: I have tested your code with my API key and I don't get the above error. Autocomplete works without problem for me. Are you certain that your API key is valid and fully working? Also do you still get this error on an Android simulator?